# React: 404/No folder structure after running `npm run build`

Tags: reactjs, apache, npm, create-react-app

I can access my index page perfectly with the following apache config

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName MyReactAppSite

        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/MyReactAppSite/client/build/

    </VirtualHost>
```

in my App.js folder I have the following code

```
<Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
```

So after logging in app routes to http://MyReactAppSite/home

**Works perfectly with >>** `npm run start`

**404 not found >>** `npm run build` followed by `serve -s build`

When I look inside the /build folder there is no /home folder so what is the proper way to get a production build of a React App.  I have read this whole page 2x  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to facilitate the REST attributes of my particular app I had to set up a .htaccess file to rout all request back into the index.html file created by my React App build.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/upload
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/tmp
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```